# Azure reservation scoped to a set of subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an EA agreement with MS and there are 100s of subscriptions in that. Out of them, 10 subscriptions are owned by my division. We are considering purchasing reservations for our division. Shared scope sounds exciting to us, but we are worried our reservations will flow out to the other 90 subscriptions if I enable scope as shared.

How can we make sure that my reservation only applies to the 10 subscriptions we have?

Comment: Quoting the Azure Portal: "Shared - The reservation discount is applied to the matching resources in eligible subscriptions within your billing context. **For enterprise customers, the billing context is the enrollment.** So there does not seem to be a way to share it across multiple subscriptions. You would need to split it per subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the Azure Portal:

> Shared - The reservation discount is applied to the matching resources in eligible subscriptions within your billing context. For enterprise customers, the billing context is the enrollment.

So there does not seem to be a way to share it across multiple subscriptions. You would need to split it per subscription in your case.